# Too much .dlls in bin folder - Microsoft SharePoint Solution

Tags: sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2013

I have created a small Microsoft SharePoint solution with the following references:

[image]

But i have only the following references in my project.

[image]

Why adds Visual Studio all those dlls to my output folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way Office SDK produces SharePoint projects. You can have a look to the .targets files in Visual Studio's installation directory. The step load and add a bunch of extra dlls that may not be required in your case.
I really wish they'd do an optimization work on that part.
In our case as we're building a product on top of SharePoint and we wanted the download of the installation media to be fast, we included a post build script in out CI to delete the dlls we actually don't need.

Comment: Can i simly delete all dlls except the referenced dlls and the dlls of the solution?

Comment: For the most I'd say yes but after your ci steps (build, unit tests...) And with a trial and error method, you might actually need a few of those in certain situations depending on what you're doing. Although everything you need should be either already at destination or in solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late for you but I think SharePoint copies all of the dlls that are shown as dependencies in your references.  E.g. the microsoft.sharepoint dll has other dependencies that are also copied.

You can stop them from copying by selecting the referenced dll then click properties and set "Copy Local" to be false. Just doing this for the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll saved me almost 6GB in my solution files!

[image]